there error while try initialize terraform aws file in vscode
terraform init
Initializing the backend...
Initializing provider plugins...

Finding latest version of hashicorp/aws...
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│
│ Error while installing hashicorp/aws v5.44.0: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws: failed to retrieve
│ authentication checksums for provider: 404 Not Found returned from releases.hashicorp.com


I try to browse "releases.hashicorp.com"
error : HashiCorp , This content is not currently
available in your region.
PS C:\Users\ghass\Desktop\share_app\Devops-Tools-Documentation-main\Terraform\AWS\Ubuntu_EC2> terraform --version
Terraform v1.8.0
on windows_386

I try initialize terraform aws file in vscode

in the future if you could please provide a working example and as much information as possible to reproduce the issue that would be great! For now, I've tried to reproduce your problem and it worked for me. I imagine the issue might be with your configuration. My working example (worked on VSCode) is below. Feel free to let me know if you have any questions
terraform {
    required_providers {
        aws = { source = "hashicorp/aws"
        version = "5.44"
        }
    }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

Result:
$ terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "5.44.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/aws v5.44.0...
- Installed hashicorp/aws v5.44.0 (signed by HashiCorp)


thank ,working example as you said , still error

@GhassanAbdullah What version of terraform are you using? terraform -version it might also be worth copying exactly what I have (with your AWS region) so we can pinpoint the issue.

Thank, PS C:\Users\ghass\Desktop\share_app\Devops-Tools-Documentation-main\Terraform\AWS\Ubuntu_EC2> terraform --version Terraform v1.8.0 on windows_386

@GhassanAbdullah Sorry I'm just looking back over this, was this resolved? And what I meant is can you post the exact code you are running and all relevant files? ie. main.tf and providers.tf, or any other files that are used in the directory.
